# disable enable a textfield dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onfocus

Hi I was trying to make a textfield dynamic. This is my code

```
 <input type="text" id="test1" value ="dynamic" onfocus="this.disabled=true" onblur="this.disabled=false">
    <input type="text" id="test2">
```

so fields get disabled perfectly but doesnt get enabled on blur. If any one here can solve my problem that would be great.

Comment: blur doesn't get sent on disabled inputs. I'm pretty sure nothing gets sent on disabled input. what do you need this for?

Comment: no you can fire `onblur` on `disabled` fields check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvLp2/)

Comment: Isn't this the exact opposite of expected functionality?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Trying to piss people off by disabling the text field on focus and reenabling it on blur? lol

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Perhaps in this situation it is better to make the field readonly and add some custom class to make it look like it is disabled.</strike>

Since disabled element are well... disabled :)

**EDIT**

I've done some testing and it gets enabled again on blur!

http://jsfiddle.net/dfhHz/

You still need to click outside the input to trigger the blur ofcourse

**EDIT2**

WHat would you like to achieve. Since this functionality looks a bit strange (disable on focus and enable on blur) to me :)

Comment: @Rohit Sharma: aha! k. Than just makes the field readonly instead of disabled (I'm on Chrome so can't test it...)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use onmouseover and onmouseout events on your text field instead ?

```
<input type="text" id="test1" value="dynamic" onmouseover="this.disabled=true" onmouseout="this.disabled=false">
```